# Python Profiling: What does "method 'poll' of 'select.poll' objects"?

Tags: python, methods, profiling

I have profiled my python code using python's `cProfile` module and got the following results:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 13937860 96351.331    0.007 96351.331    0.007 {method 'poll' of 'select.poll' objects}
 13930480  201.012    0.000  201.012    0.000 {built-in method posix.read}
 13937860  180.207    0.000 97129.916    0.007 connection.py:897(wait)
 13937860  118.066    0.000 96493.283    0.007 selectors.py:356(select)
  6968925   86.243    0.000 97360.129    0.014 queues.py:91(get)
 13937860   76.067    0.000  194.402    0.000 selectors.py:224(register)
 13937860   64.667    0.000 97194.582    0.007 connection.py:413(_poll)
 13930480   64.365    0.000  279.040    0.000 connection.py:374(_recv)
31163538/17167548   64.083    0.000  106.596    0.000 records.py:230(__getattribute__)
 13937860   57.454    0.000  264.845    0.000 selectors.py:341(register)
...
```

Obviously, my program spends most of its running time in the `method 'poll' of 'select.poll' objects`. However, I have no clue when and why this method is called and what I have to change in my program in order to reduce these method calls.

So, what could I look for to avoid this bottleneck in my code?

I am using 64bit python 3.5 with numpy and [sharedmem](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sharedmem/0.3) on a Linux server.

Comment: I'm using Python Multiprocessing and I tested my core process. I see the same behavior in the results. I don't have any pool maps implemented. The core is receiving data from Queues. As I understand, this seems to be an internal method used by the process, but I don't understand 100% where/how is used.

Comment: @eduardosufan Pool uses queues, too, to retrieve results from different processes. So what is written here with regards to `Pool` applies to you as well.

Answer (score 13):

Methods that execute inside a different process (for example with a `ProcessPoolExecutor`) are not captured by `cProfile`. So the `select.poll` is just showing your main process waiting for results from the other processes.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some experiments I figured it out: My program does most of its work wrapped in sharedmem's parallel map method:

```
with sharedmem.MapReduce() as pool:
    pool.map(myMethod, argumentList)
```

However, `myMethod` does not appear anywhere in the profile log. Moreover, no method called from within `myMethod` is being profiled properly. Instead, all time the program spends in `myMethod` goes under `method 'poll' of 'select.poll' objects` in the log. That is, profiling does not work well with sharedmem's `map` method and I have to find a different way to optimize my program.

**To profile the program anyway**, I see two major options:

1. To replace `pool.map` with a classical `map` or a for loop or
2. To write a wrapper around `myMethod` that does the profiling of this subroutine and saves or prints the results.

Of course, the first option does not capture behaviour specific to parallelization (e.g. if one process has to wait for another), and the execution time is larger. However, if the parallelization is 'trivial' (no interaction between processes) and we are interested in the relative time spent in different sections of the code, this may be the way to go. Note that comparing the original profiling results with the profiling result from the altered function allows us to deduce approximately how much time is spent where in the original code if we consider the number of cores.

The second option has the disadvantage that we may end up with many profiling results though we would like to have a single overview. However, often it is possible to parallelize the code in chunks. That is, we could split the list of arguments into sublists so that each core (process) is executing the wrapper only once.

```
def myMethodWrapper(argumentListPart):
   return [myMethod(arg) for arg in argumentListPart]

def myMethodProfiler(argumentListPart):
   # replace the line below with the profiling command you are using
   return profile(myMethodWrapper, argumentListPart)
```

That way, you will only have as many results as you have cores on your computer. Note that the wrappers must be defined on the module level or (if `myMethod` belongs to an object) on the object level, as you will get a pickling error otherwise.

I am pretty sure that it is possible to aggregate profiling results computationally if the respective results are saved to files. I have not implemented this to date, however. An answer containing such code would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the different way you used in the end?

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the python library. It's used to read events from I/O. By definition it will wait for events so it will take longer. Not something that you should be changing.

Comment: What does it mean to read events from I/O? (I did read the documentation on select.poll but it did not help me.) Does I/O (solely) mean reading/writing files and command line characters? Even if I cannot change the method itself, I might want to change where/how often it is called. However, I have never explicitely called this method in my code. It must be called in some subroutine. Do you have any guess what such subroutine could deal with?

Comment: Usually files, but could be anything with fileno / file descriptor. Look into the source file /Python35/Lib/selectors.py